# Animating Label Color Changes In Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I have an indicator in my app, which has an icon (label) with a numeric value overlaid on it.

I want to bring attention to the fact the value changed, by changing the color of the label icon.  I can do this by swapping out a different image made using a different color.

But I would like to return it back to its original color, and still see the color change and change back on the screen.  I thought I might be able to use animation to do this, but I can't figure out how.

Update:

Applying Francesco's suggestion, like so:

```
replace(labelstd, labelhlt, CommonTransitions.createFade(500));
replace(labelhlt, labelstd, CommonTransitions.createFade(500));
```

I find that it does not fade to the highlight color, and then fade back, as I would like.  It fades to the highlight color then instantly flips back.  I assume that this is because the fades are actually happening in parallel.

Do I need to use threads to handle this, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: `Label.setIcon(...)` is not enough? Do you want something like a fade effect? In that case, there is `Container.replace(Component current, Component next, Transition t)` that you can use to switch two Labels. As transition, you can use `CommonTransitions.createFade(int duration)` or any other transition provided by that class.

Comment: yes, the problem with setIcon is that it makes a permanent change, where I am looking to change it then change it back, like a glow effect.  I have just played a bit with the replace function and Fade transition - it looks like this is exactly what I am looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Francesco for the suggestion.  Here is how I made this work to create a "pulse" type graphic effect:

```
   public void fade()
   {
      replace(imageLabel, fadeImage, CommonTransitions.createFade(300), () -> reverseFade(), 0);
   }

   private void reverseFade()
   {
      replace(fadeImage, imageLabel, CommonTransitions.createFade(250));
   }
```